# Removing and adding elements to ConcurrentSkipListSet while iterating

Tags: java, collections

Is it safe to remove and add elements to `ConcurrentSkipListSet` while iterating over it:

```
ConcurrentSkipListSet<Element> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Element>(myComparator);
for(Element e : set)
{
   if(condition)
   {
      set.remove(e);
      set.add(anotherE);
   }
}
```

where `e` and `anotherE` are equal by provided comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe. From [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html):

> Insertion, removal, and access operations safely execute concurrently
>   by multiple threads. Iterators are weakly consistent, returning
>   elements reflecting the state of the set at some point at or since the
>   creation of the iterator. They do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with
>   other operations.